# Which of the following contains low fibre?

Tags: cats, health, feeding, cat-food

1. wet cat food or
2. dry cat food.

I need this information to better feed my lactating mother cat.

Comment: the information you ask for is printed on the  containers of catfood and on the different brands websites.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question because each manufacturer has different compositions for their pet foods. Even different brands of a food type (dry / wet) of the same manufacturer can have different compositions. Please read the labels on the food containers as Trond Hansen suggests.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Elmy and Trond  Hanseen :)